# Solve quadratic congruence using the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: congruences, quadratic-reciprocity, chinese-remainder-theorem

Solve $x^2 \equiv$ -1 (mod 205) 
I have that as 205 = 5 x 41 this becomes:

$x^2$ $\equiv $ -1 (mod 5) 
$x^2$ $\equiv $ -1 (mod 41)

then i'm not sure where to go. I can see 32 is a solution but I don't know how to get there properly! Thanks

Comment: Is it that you're not sure how to solve $x^2\equiv-1\pmod5$? or that, once you have solved the two congruences, you're not sure how to apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve $x^2 \equiv -1 mod 5 $

Comment: Well, there are fancy methods that work for large moduli, but for small moduli like 5 and 41, you may as well just try $x=1$, $x=2$, and so on, until you find a solution; once you have found a solution, call it $Q$, then $-Q$ will be the only other solution (when the modulus is prime).

Comment: Usually, you would first check, if there are any solutions to $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ at all. The appropiate tool here would be the _First Supplement to the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity_. If there are solutions, then they are among $x=1,\dots,\frac{p-1}{2}$, which is easy to check by hand for small $p$.

Answer (score 1):

As other users in comments have recommanded, because you have prime modulii and they are relatively small you can check the number form $1$ to $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and obtain solutions. But here's another one:

Try adding 5 or 41 respectively to the RHS until you get a square. So you need to find a square of the form $5k - 1$ and a square of $41n - 1$ for some $n,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. It's easy to obtain that $4$ is a square of the form $5k-1$ and $81$ is the square of the form $41n - 1$ so you have:

$$x^2 \equiv -1 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \implies x \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$$
$$x^2 \equiv -1 \equiv 81 \pmod {41} \implies x \equiv \pm 9 \pmod {41}$$

Then you have 4 cases to check and you'll get $4$ solutions using Chinese Remainder Theorem.